# (recyclerview-selection)Changing SelectionTracker during run time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, androidx

I have to change `SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything()` and `SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything()` by a button click.

[image]

Showing this error, when I change `SelectionPredicates` on `Runtime`

In the `onCreate()` firstly create, SelectionBuilder object

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ...
         selectionBuilder = SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>(
            "mySelection",
            recyclerView,
            StableIdKeyProvider(recyclerView),
            MyItemDetailsLookup(recyclerView),
            StorageStrategy.createLongStorage()
        )
        tracker = customerBuild.build()
        adapter.tracker = tracker
        ...
 }
```

In `selectoinBuilder` i don't put any word about `SelectionPredicate` on here, coz it will configure on when user select one of the button.

```
 single.setOnClickListener {
            tracker?.clearSelection()
            tracker = selectionBuilder.withSelectionPredicate(
                SelectionPredicates.createSelectSingleAnything()
            ).build()
            adapter.tracker = tracker
        }



multi.setOnClickListener {
                tracker?.clearSelection()
                tracker =selectionBuilder.withSelectionPredicate(
                    SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything()
                ).build()
                adapter.tracker = tracker
        }
tracker?.addObserver(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>() {
            override fun onItemStateChanged(key: Long, selected: Boolean) {
                super.onItemStateChanged(key, selected)
                Log.i("Hello", "changes is index $key, and value is $selected")
            }
        })
```

Thanks you!

Comment: A little late but for anyone that gets this error again,try setting the adapter to the recyclerview before setting the tracker to the adapter. That did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

In the StableIdKeyProvider in selectionBuilder, change the argument from recyclerView to adapter, because keyProviders are the source of selection keys, which is the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should set recyclervew.adapter its value first, before initializing Selection Tracker builder